# Jquery mobile how to force target page refresh after changePage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there any way to refresh the target page after changePage.

I really search but nothing works for me.

Comment: Are you using single-page templates or the multi-page template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the following solutions:

**1 -** Use `$(location).attr('href',"your_html.html");`

**Example:**

Since you're using single page template, let's suppose that you have two jQuery Mobile pages (`#page_1` and `#page_2`) in 2 separate HTML files (`page_1.html` and `page_2.html`).

If you want to navigate from `#page_1` (which is in `page_1.html`) to `#page_2` (which is in `page_2.html`), you'd use:

```
$(location).attr('href',"page_2.html");
```

***Check the complete example below:***

**-** `page_1.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#mlink").click(function() {
                    $(location).attr('href',"page_2.html");
                });

                $("#mlink_2").click(function() {
                    $(location).attr('href',"page_1.html");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="page_1" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="content">
                PAGE 1<br>

                <!-- WHEN CLICKING ON THIS LINK, YOU'LL GO TO #page_2 in page_2.html 
                WITH PAGE REFRESH -->
                <a id="mlink">GO TO PAGE 2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**-** `page_2.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>          

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#mlink").click(function() {
                    $(location).attr('href',"page_2.html");
                });

                $("#mlink_2").click(function() {
                    $(location).attr('href',"page_1.html");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="page_2" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="content">
                PAGE 2<br>

                <!-- WHEN CLICKING ON THIS LINK, YOU'LL GO TO #page_1 in page_1.html 
                WITH PAGE REFRESH -->
                <a id="mlink_2">GO TO PAGE 1</a>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**2 -** Try using `$.mobile.changePage("your_html.html", { reloadPage: true });`

Considering the previous example, and supposing that you want to navigate from `#page_1` to `#page_2`, you'd simply have to replace the method `$(location).attr('href',"page_2.html");` with:

```
$.mobile.changePage("page_2.html", { reloadPage: true });
```

For more information about the method `$.mobile.changePage()` and its option `reloadPage`, check the following link: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: i use object url like this #page

Comment: I'm confused... what's the problem? Give me more details mate :S.

Comment: `your_html.html` should be the name of your HTML page containing your jQuery mobile page `#page`. Let me know if I'm clear or not. Since you're using single page template, you only have one jQuery mobile page in an HTML file, so the solution above should be appropriate.

Comment: Ok, I re-edited my post. Have a look and let me know if some things are unclear :)

Comment: I have all the html pages in one file. In that case how can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

This may be what you (or others) are really looking for:

`data-ajax="false"`

```
<a href="/" data-ajax="false">
    <img id="mainLogo" src="logo.svg" width="215" />
</a>
```

This will bypass ajax behavior.

> [Linking without Ajax](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/navigation-linking-pages/)
>
> Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external",
>   data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax.
>   Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh with no animated
>   transition. Both attributes (rel="external" and data-ajax="false")
>   have the same effect, but a different semantic meaning: rel="external"
>   should be used when linking to another site or domain, while
>   data-ajax="false" is useful for simply opting a page within your
>   domain from being loaded via Ajax. Because of security restrictions,
>   the framework always opts links to external domains out of the Ajax
>   behavior.