# jQuery mobile force full reload when link clicked

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a "normal" link in my jqm page like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/mobile/page.php?attribute=value">
```

And if I click it it won't properly refresh taking into account the attribute value and loading everything that's needed for it dynamically based on the attribute value. I understand that this is due to the fact that jqm tries to do an ajax call like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829006/jquery-mobile-page-doesnt-refresh):

```
 When you use pageChange an Ajax request will be made to that url and it will be
 loaded only the content inside the div with data-role="page". So everything you
 have out of this element will be ignored (JS and CSS).
```

So, I found out in the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html) that I should use `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled=false;` or `rel=external` on links or `target=_blank` on the link.

Strange thing though for me is that only when I set the `target=_blank` property to my links will this truly happen. So, am wondering if someone had this kind of a problem and how did you solve it? The thing is, I would like to refrain myself form using `target=_blank` as it opens a new tab in my browser (as expected, but this is not nice from users' POV).

jqm version I use is 1.2

Comment: use `$.mobile.changePage('url', { reloadPage: true });`. **reloadPage** Forces a reload of a page, even if it is already in the DOM of the page container. 
Used only when the 'to' argument of changePage() is a URL.

Comment: Hi Omar, thanks for your answer though it really doesn't work for me and neither does the Vinay's answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This question now at the top of google search results, so figured I'd answer:

Use the data-ajax attribute and set it to false to force reload upon clicking a link:

```
data-ajax="false"
```

use it like:

```
<a href="/" data-ajax="false">
    <img id="mainLogo" src="logo.svg" width="215" />
</a>
```

And then your link will force reload the page!

> [Linking without Ajax](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/navigation-linking-pages/)
>
> Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external",
>   data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax.
>   Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh with no animated
>   transition. Both attributes (rel="external" and data-ajax="false")
>   have the same effect, but a different semantic meaning: rel="external"
>   should be used when linking to another site or domain, while
>   data-ajax="false" is useful for simply opting a page within your
>   domain from being loaded via Ajax. Because of security restrictions,
>   the framework always opts links to external domains out of the Ajax
>   behavior.

Parts taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22951472

Comment: Is there an easy way to tell JQM that you want all your links this way?

Answer (score -1):

Make function for the onclick event of the link.See the below code example.Hope this helps!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadPage(url){
document.location.href = url;
}
<script/>
<a href="#" onClick="loadPage('http://www.mysite.com/mobile/page.php?attribute=value');">
```